# React Router <LINK>How to get value of href in Jest Test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jestjs

New to **React JS** and writing a test case in **Jest** to check the link in the component. I am using `react-router` and for the link using `<LINK to="{{pathname: link}}" />Link</LINK>`, I'm using react-router 2.0. I saw some posts that suggest you need to stub the react-router one way or the other but those are all related to the version 1.0. Do I still need to do something similar? I am able to get the node by selecting with class but I cannot get the value of `href`.

```
 let link = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(widgetComponent, 'link');
 let linkNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(link);
 let renderedLink = linkNode.attributes['href'].value;
 expect(renderedLink).toContain('test-link');
```

Please advise.

Comment: Anyone has an answer for this?

Answer (score 4):

I think this might work if you want to use [enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/). You can do something like this if you only care about matching the href (or the Link "to" prop):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

const wrapper = shallow(widgetComponent);
expect(wrapper.find(Link).props().to).toEqual('test-link');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my 2 attempts, they are not working either:

**UPDATE**

In my test case finding the `<p>` tag works with:

```
myDomNode.querySelectorAll('p')[0] // Success = [object HTMLParagraphElement]
```

But finding the `<a>` tag generated by `react-router` `Link` fails:

```
myDomNode.querySelectorAll('a')[0] // = undefined
```

**My React Component**

```
export default class MyHeaderMenu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <Link to={`/`}>HOME</Link> {" | "} 

         <p>junk rat</p>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**ORIGINAL POST**

**at top of test file add:**
import { Link } from 'react-router';

**ATTEMPT 1**

**Jest test**

```
it('Home text appears', () => {
   const myDomNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(instance);

   // This returns undefined: myDomNode.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]
   // so innerHTML is failing.
   const linkNode = myDomNode.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML

   expect(linkNode).toContain('Home');
});
```

**ATTEMPT 2**

**Jest test 2**

```
it('Home text appears', () => {
   const myDomNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(instance);

   const myLinks = TestUtils.findAllInRenderedTree(instance,       
      function(component) {
         if (component === Link) {
            return true;
         }
      }
   );

   expect( myLinks[0].textContent ).toContain('Home');

});
```

**Here's the top section of my Jest test file:**

```
// __tests__/MyHeaderMenu-test.js

jest.unmock('../app/components/MyHeaderMenu');

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

import MyHeaderMenu from '../app/components/MyHeaderMenu';


describe('MyHeaderMenu', () => {

    const instance = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <MyHeaderMenu />
    );

    it //... test cases start here ...
```